# Python : ValueError: invalid literal for float()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm tring to create a dictionary importing data from an excel file converted in csv and I want to convert the string value of the dictionary into float, but I get in return this error `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 437,33`

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = {}
my_dict = defaultdict(lambda : 0, my_dict)

with open('excel_csv_file.csv', 'rb') as file_object:
    reader = csv.reader(file_object, delimiter=';')
    for x in reader:
        my_dict[(x[0], x[1])] = x[2]

my_dict = dict((k, float(v)) for k,v in my_dict.iteritems())
print my_dict
```

This is what my_dict looks like

```
{('11605', 'TV'): '437,33',
 ('10850', 'SMARTPHONE'): '163,47',
 ('11380', 'TV'): '1911,72',
 ('11177', 'SMARTPHONE'): '255,80',
 ('11237', 'TABLET'): '382,28',
 ('11238', 'TABLET'): '458,01',
 ('11325', 'TABLET'): '309,55',
 ...}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Also, is there a way to convert the string value inside the tuple key into an int? (for instance `('11605', 'TV')` to `(11605, 'TV')`)?

Comment: Sounds like your data comes from somewhere where people use `,` to separate the integer and fraction parts of a number. Python expects `.` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python uses `.` (period) to separate the integer and fraction parts of a floating-point number, but your data uses `,` (comma).

To convert to `int`, you can use value unpacking:

```
line my_dict = dict(((int(k1), k2), float(v.replace(',', '.'))) for (k1,k2),v in my_dict.iteritems())
```

Since you’re using Python 2.7, you can also use a `dict` comprehension to make this simpler:

```
line my_dict = {(int(k1), k2): float(v.replace(',', '.')) for (k1,k2),v in my_dict.iteritems()}
```

---

**Bonus:**

If you have input from countries other than the US, and you expect you might run into other issues similar to your decimal separation one, you can use the `locale` module. If you start the script with

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

you can use the various functions in the locale module `locale.atof`) instead of the built-in conversion methods like `float`, and it will automatically handle the user’s locale settings.

Comment: I’ve added mention of the `locale` module. For simple scripts it’s often overkill, but if you live outside the US or expect a lot of people to use your code, it can be useful.

Comment: Somebody downvoted this, and I don’t know why. If there’s a problem with it, could you please explain?

Comment: Using your code I get the same error and I think that now it's because of the period used to separate thousands instead of the comma ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2.688.44

Comment: The sample data you gave doesn’t have thousands separators. If your actual data does, then you’ll need to handle that somehow. It looks like `locale.atof` supports digit grouping, or you can just `.replace` it with the empty string, at the cost of breaking if any of the input uses `.` as a decimal separator.

Comment: Thank you, I resolved using locale.atof ! I don't know why someone downvoted your answer, it's just great!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> float('382,28')
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 382,28
```

Because Python expects `.` for separating the integer and fraction parts of a number. The easiest thing you can do is to replace it:

```
>>> float('382,28'.replace(",", "."))
382.28
```

--

```
my_dict = dict((k, float(v.replace(",", "."))) for k, v in my_dict.iteritems())
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first error, you must change your floats Strings data that looks like, for example `"22,32"` to `"22.32"`, replace the `,` for `.` .
 For the second question, if you want to get an int from a string, just do int("43") for example.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel H already said that in [his Bonus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44078518/), but for short I would put the following instruction:

Set locale to spanish, and use `locale.atof` instead of `float`.

In code it would be:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC,"es_ES")
locale.atof("123,45")
```

in your case, use

```
my_dict = dict((k, locale.atof(v)) for k,v in my_dict.iteritems())
```

instead of

```
my_dict = dict((k, float(v)) for k,v in my_dict.iteritems())
```